# Open installed chrome extension on web site

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to open a Chrome extension through an event listener, e.g onClick, with vanilla JS on a simple web page? I.e have the same functionality as the Chrome web store.

[image: Chrome-web-store]

The extension I wish to open is NOT created by me, but is a third-party extension the user has already installed via Chrome web store, namely the one on the picture above.

Comment: Only if the extension has such code. As for the Web Store, it's a privileged site that can use internal APIs.